# Count of Object in pageblock table

Tags: visualforce, soql

I have  a requirement where I  have to load a pageblocktable in  the following way.
Column 1-- Assigned to, Column 2-- Total No Processed, Column 3--Percentage completed.

I have a query that returns the count of the files processed but the query uses the COUNT(Name). How do I pass the count value to the table?

Answer (score 1):

It will be great if you explain this in more detail. 
As per my understanding till yet, 
**Either You want to show the List of records in Table on VF page**

** ********************** In Controller (Apex Class) **********************

```
  public Integer MYCount {get;set;}
    "
    "
    List <Your_Object__c> lstObj =[select count(id) tmpCount,Name,Assigned_to__c,Total_No_Processed__c, Percentage_Completed__c  from Your_Object__c];

    MYCount = Integer.valueOf(lstObj.get('tmpCount'));
```

********************** In Your VF Page  **********************

```
 "
    "

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstObj}" var="item" rendered="true">
                <apex:column value="{!item.Assigned_to__c}"/> 
               <apex:column value="{!item.Total_No_Processed__c}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!item.Percentage_Completed__c }"/>

               <!-- ********** OR to Access your Count Value ************ -->
               <apex:column value="{! MYCount}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Please, let me know if you facing in issue. Giving some code or hint will be more usefull. Do Cudo if found useful in answer.